# Pass variable name as a string to task in verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I would like to create a task for debug purposes in which I can print the name of the variable and assign the value to that variable. I can think of these ways to do it with the following **pseudo-code**:

1) pass the variable by reference and the value, which seems to work fine and the variable gets assigned, but I can not figure out how to print its name.

```
reg myVarName;  
debug_message1(myVarName, 1'b1);

// assigns myVarName=1'b1;
// Expected print output: "The variable name is myVarName and its value is 1"
task debug_message1(ref reg var, reg val);

  var = val;
  print("The variable name is %s and its value is %d", var.name, var);
endtask
```

2) pass variable name as a string, which makes it easy to print, but I don't know how to convert the string that contains the name of the variable to the actual variable, so I could assign to it.

```
reg myVarName;
debug_message2("myVarName", 1'b1);

// Need to somehow assign myVarName=1'b1;
// Printed output: "The variable name is myVarName and its value is 1"
task debug_message2;
  input string var;
  input    reg val;

  `var` = val; // need to make assignment here 
  print("The variable name is %s and its value is %d", var, val);
endtask
```

3) Pass the variable, its name as a string, and the value, which does not like the second and the third arguments, because they are defined when calling the task, which gives the following error message:

```
Illegal connection to the ref port 'varname' of function/task 'debug_message3',formal argument should have same type as actual argument.
```

The same kind of error comes up for the 'val' argument.

```
reg myVarName;
debug_message3(myVarName, "myVarName", 1'b1);

// Assign myVarName=1'b1;
// Printed output: "The variable name is myVarName and its value is 1"
task debug_message3(ref reg var, string varname, reg val);

  var = val; // need to make assignment here 
  print("The variable name is %s and its value is %d", varname, var);
endtask
```

**Is there a way to implement any of the 1, 2 or 3 approaches?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a macro to do this instead of a task

```
`define debug_message(Var,Value) \
begin \
  Var = Value; \
  $display("The variable name is %s and its value is %d", `"Var`", Var); \
end
```

A macro treats its arguments as just text, giving you the ability to reinterpret them as identifiers or strings. The `` `" `` instead of `"` is what lets lets you have macro arguments inside a string.

Comment: Dave, this is exactly what I needed. How do I fix the following: _define set_arg(var) begin if ($value$plusargs(`"var`=%d", var)) $display("%d => %s", var, `"var`"); end_

Comment: See edited answer.